# apt-get install php5-imap (missing dependancies)

Tags: 14.04, apt, apache2, php

I am trying to install php5-imap but I get the error that dependancies are missing. But they are not!

The error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-imap : Depends: phpapi-20090626
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

dpkg -l | grep php returns this:

```
ii  libapache2-mod-php5                  5.5.37+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~precise+1 server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
ii  php-http                             1.4.1-1                                                 PHP PEAR module for HTTP related stuff
ii  php-pear                             5.5.37+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~precise+1 PEAR - PHP Extension and Application Repository
ii  php5                                 5.5.37+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~precise+1 server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
ii  php5-cli                             5.5.37+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~precise+1 command-line interpreter for the php5 scripting language
ii  php5-common                          5.5.37+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~precise+1 Common files for packages built from the php5 source
ii  php5-curl                            5.5.37+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~precise+1 CURL module for php5
ii  php5-dev                             5.5.37+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~precise+1 Files for PHP5 module development
ii  php5-gd                              5.5.37+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~precise+1 GD module for php5
ii  php5-imagick                         3.3.0-1+deb.sury.org~precise+2                          Provides a wrapper to the ImageMagick library
ii  php5-json                            1.3.9-1+deb.sury.org~precise+3                          JSON module for php5
ii  php5-mcrypt                          5.5.37+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~precise+1 MCrypt module for php5
rc  php5-mysql                           5.5.7+dfsg-1+sury.org~precise+1                         MySQL module for php5
ii  php5-mysqlnd                         5.5.37+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~precise+1 MySQL module for php5 (Native Driver)
ii  php5-sqlite                          5.5.37+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~precise+1 SQLite module for php5
ii  pkg-php-tools                        1.21+deb.sury.org~precise+1                             various packaging tools and scripts for PHP packages
```

From the reading I have done, phpapi is part of php-cgi, php-cli and other packages that I have installed.

I also found that php5-fpm is reporting a similar error except with php5-common which is clearly in the list of installed packages.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you check [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)? If you did but something didnt work, [edit] your question explaining it.

Comment: After going around and around trying to figure this out, it ultimately ended up being an old repository. I removed it and the current one picked up all the required upgrades. A little painful to find.

Comment: Then I encourage you to post an answer yourself as it might be helpful for someone else in the future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going around and around trying to figure this out, it ultimately ended up being an old repository. I removed it and the current one picked up all the required upgrades. A little painful to find.